# Why does this textured NSWindow suddenly change its background gradient when resizing?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nswindow

Can someone please tell me, why the background gradient of the textured NSWindow in this app suddenly changes, when you make the window a little bit smaller?

[image: bigger window, gradient 1] [image: smaller window, gradient 2]

This is the minimal example I could find, that exhibits this behaviour. [App & Source](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/253418/spiky_weird-gradient.zip) are available via Dropbox.

-- Updates:

1. If you put the slider lower,the gradient does **not** change when resizing the window:
   [image: slider lower, small window, no gradient change]
2. Also, the change seems to happen when the distance between the slider and the window's right border gets smaller than the HIG says it should be.

Comment: Any new on this ? How to force avoiding force the normal gradient to draw ? I have the same issue with an NStextField, if it is more than a third of the window width is just make a darker ugly gradient....

Answer (score 0):

It is really interesting question =)
I don't shure, but guess, this problem is connected to layers displaying.

If you still want to use textured window, you can put additional NSView object in the interface builder between NSView and NSSlider (NSWindow -> NSView -> **NSView** -> NSSlider). It fixes the bug.